# What is the purpose of [marks for name, marks in marksheet]

Tags: python, list

Here is the code

```
marksheet = []

for _ in range(0,int(input())):

    marksheet.append([input(), float(input())])

second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]

print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest]))
```

Doesn't the `[marks for name, marks in marksheet]` produce the same list as marksheet?  So couldn't we get the same result with second_highest = sorted(list(set(marksheet)))[1] ?

Comment: `marksheet` is a list of 2-item lists. The list comprehension just extracts the second item from each list, i.e. going from `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]` to `[y1, y2]`. This is easily confirmed in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: `second_highest` implies that you want `reverse=True`?

Answer (score 2):

Here, I would add a small contribution intended for all new coders with no experience.

The line [marks for name, marks in marksheet] needs to be read as

```
-> marks----for----name, marks----in----marksheet
```

Initially, I too was confused as I was reading it as

```
-> marks for name,----marks in marksheet
```

However silly this may sound, I have to admit that I faced this problem. After staring at the simple line for a while, it just came to me and I shifted my perspective.
If this answer could help anyone, I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `chepner`, `marksheet` is a list of list (2 items inside inner list).

For a input of 2, `marksheet` would be

```
marksheet = [['Mark' , 1.2 ], ['Sam', 2.0]]
```

Now, this list comprehension --> `[marks for name, marks in marksheet]` takes each list item in the marksheet list, and then just takes out the marks from each element.

so, the output would be a new list --> `[1.2, 2.0]` which is different from the original `marksheet` list.